# Differentiation of matrix exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I'm with the following problem and I'd like to know if my answer makes sense. I'd appreciate any suggestion to improve it. Thanks :)

> Let $X(t)= \int_0^tA(t) dt$, where $A(t)$ is a continuous $n\times n$ matrix. Show that in general we can't conclude  \begin{align*}\frac{d}{dt} \exp(X(t))\not=A(t)\exp(X(t)) \tag{*}\end{align*}
>   But if $[A(t),A(s)]=0$ for all $t$ and $s$ in $\mathbb{R}$, where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the commutator, then the equality in $(*)$ is true.

Since $\exp(X(t))$ is absolutely and uniform convergent for any $t$, we can develop in a power series expansion and the derivative is element by element. Thus

\begin{align*}\frac{d}{dt} \exp(X(t))= A(t)+\frac{1}{2}\big(A(t)X(t)+X(t)A(t)\big)+\frac{1}{3!}\big(A(t)X^2(t)+X(t)A(t)X(t)+X^2(t)A(t)\big)+\ldots+\end{align*}

and not necessarily $[A(t),X(t)]=0$ for all $t$, therefore the equality in $(*)$ does not hold for all matrices.

Now suppose that $[A(t),A(s)]=0$ for all $t$ and $s$ in $\mathbb{R}$. We will show that $[A(t),X(t)]=0$. Let $\mathscr{P}$ a tagged partition of the subinterval $[0,t]$, so let $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^n$ a finite sequence of points which are a partition of $[0,t]$ and let  $\{t_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be the tags of $\mathscr{P}$, that is, $a_{i-1}\le t_i\le a_i$ holds for each $i=1,\ldots, n$. Then we will show that $$A(t)\mathscr{R}(A(t),\mathscr{P})=\mathscr{R}(A(t),\mathscr{P})A(t)$$ where $\mathscr{R}(A(t),\mathscr{P})$ is the Riemann sum corresponding to $A(t)$ and the  partition $\mathscr{P}$. Then

\begin{align*}A(t)\sum_{k=1}^n\bigg( (a_k-a_{k-1}) A(t_k)\bigg)&=\sum_{k=1}^n \bigg((a_k-a_{k-1}) A(t)A(t_k)\bigg)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\bigg( (a_k-a_{k-1}) A(t_k)A(t)\bigg)=\sum_{k=1}^n\bigg( (a_k-a_{k-1}) A(t_k)\bigg)A(t) \end{align*}

Now let $\mathscr{P}$ a tagged partition of $[0,t]$, such that $\|\mathscr{R}(A(t),\mathscr{P})-X(t)\|<\epsilon$, where $\|\cdot \|$ is the operator norm. Then

\begin{align*}\|A(t)X(t)-X(t)A(t)\|&\le \|A(X-\mathscr{R})\|+\|\mathscr{R}A-A\mathscr{R}\|+\|(\mathscr{R}-X)A\|\\
&\le \|A\| \|X-\mathscr{R}\|+\|\mathscr{R}-A\|\|A\|\\
&<2\|A\|\epsilon\end{align*}

Letting $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, gives us $[A(t),X(t)]=0$ as desired.Then using the above result, is clear that the equality on $(*)$ holds.

Comment: Is the $\neq$ sign in the 'equation' $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\exp{(X(t))} \neq A(t)\exp{(X(t))}$ actually meant to be an $=$ sign? The wording of the question seems to strongly imply that it should be an $=$ sign.

Comment: @WillR No the sign is correct.

Comment: I think it's better to find an explicit counter-example (say using 2x2 matrices) for the first claim.

Comment: @Winther Yes I think so. But almost any counter-example a find is complicated to write the exponential matrix. I was trying to find a very simple one.  ;) but I can figure out it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disprove the first statement I would construct a counter-example. Take

$$X(t) = \left(\matrix{t & t^2\\0 & 0}\right) \implies A(t) = \frac{dX(t)}{dt} = \left(\matrix{1 & 2t\\0 & 0}\right)$$ then $[A(t),A(s)] = \left(\matrix{0 & 2(s-t)\\0 & 0}\right)$ so the commutator do not vanish for $s\not=t$. We further find

$$X^n(t) = \left(\matrix{t^n & t^{n+1}\\ 0 & 0}\right) \implies e^{X(t)} = \left(\matrix{e^t & t(e^t-1)\\0 & 1}\right)$$

giving us

$$\frac{de^{X(t)}}{dt} = \left(\matrix{e^t & e^t(t+1)-1\\0 & 0}\right),~~~~~~~~ A(t) e^{X(t)} = \left(\matrix{ e^t & t(e^t+1) \\0 & 0 \\}\right)$$

and $\frac{de^{X(t)}}{dt} \not= A(t)e^{X(t)}$ for all $t\not= 0$.

Comment: Thank you. Very illustrative.